# Azure ad access token validation at python web api with respect to client app

Tags: python, azure, api, oauth-2.0, jwt

I am using azure for hosting web app and web api.

**Environment configuration :**

1. web api : Developed using django deployed/hosted on linux vm
2. Web app : Developed using Angular2 deployed/hosted on App service

**For authentication I am using OAUTH2 protocol.**

**App registration details for OAUTH2**

Under single tenant: **"my-tenant-id-121"**

1. Registered web api and provided access_as_user permissions

   - here suppose app_id/client_id : **"my-api-id-123"**
   - APP uri : **'api://my-api-id-123'**
   - scope : **'api://my-api-id-123/access_as_user'**
   - client secret is generated but not using it.
2. Registered web app and provided basic details, redirect uri etc

   - here suppose webapp app_id/client_id : **"my-webapp-id-123"**
   - Under app registration, provided api access permissions for above registered api using API permissions

**Authentication :**

1. client(web app): Using **ng2-adal library**
2. resource (web api) : using python **"jwt"** library for access token validation

I have done all the configuration, after authentication I am getting id_token for web app and access_token for postman client.

**Token Validation:**

I am validating access token at api side which I am receiving through Authorisation header.
 I have followed all the references available, through `jwt.verify()` my token getting validated. Here I am also validating audience, for id_token it is **aud: client_app_id** and when using postman I am specifying scope, in that case **aud :"api://my-api-id-123"**

Here comes the main part:

While following all process **I never used registered web api app_id i.e  "my-webapp-id-123"** anywhere.
Then how come client app getting authenticated also access token getting validated.

Also I tried to remove linking between web app and web api from azure app registration and tried to authenticate. In both cases I have received token and validated at api side.

My questions are -

1. why we need to register Web api at app registration on azure as it is not getting used?
2. In my current scenario which part I am missing, my concern is if I remove linking (on azure, at client app under api permissions) between "client_app" and "api_app", access_token /id_token retrieved at client app should not get validated at web api.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean `remove linking between web app and web api`? Could you please provide the picture about this?

Comment: On azure portal, Under azure active directory->app registrations-> {select client app}-> Api permissions-> where we select registered backend web api app. Even though we don’t add this api permission I can able to validate access token at api side.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to get access token?

Comment: 1] using postman ouath2 client: provide client_id, scope, implicit_grant, authorisation url then it will redirect to Microsoft page-> provide email n password-> once it is authenticated-> you will receive access token at postman. Also using front end angular single page web application, for which I am using ng2-adal library where I use only tenant_id, client_id and redirect uri then I get id_token

Comment: if we have removed web api permissions in you web app, we cannot require token with web api scope. We will get the error like `AADSTS650057:+Invalid+resource.+The+client+has+requested+access+to+a+resource+which+is+not+listed+in+the+requested+permissions+in+the+client`

Comment: yeah. For my case it is asking for admin consent. However it is cleared my doubt, earlier I was able to receive token as because I had removed only application permissions but there were still api permissions available in other permissions, hence able to receive token. Once I removed those permissions I am not able receive token. So it is solved my query about relationship and need for api permissions.  Thanks for your help.